# ruby on rails rake db:seed undefined method for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, seed, migrate

I am trying to set up a basic user authentication - I have the user login stuff sorted and am up to adding roles for the user.

Essentially I want my Users to have many Roles, which gives them access to Rights.

I wrote some seed data but keep getting the error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `roles' for #<Array:0x007f8c0581ba80>
```

My seed data looks like:

```
#user
user = User.create!([{ email: 'admin@admin.com', first_name: 'Admin', last_name: 'Test', password: 'admin', password_confirmation: 'admin'}])
user.roles << admins = Role.create!(:name => "Admin")

#user roles
create = Right.create!(:resource => "users", :operation => "CREATE") 
read = Right.create!(:resource => "users", :operation => "READ") 
update = Right.create!(:resource => "users", :operation => "UPDATE") 
delete = Right.create!(:resource => "users", :operation => "DELETE")

#add the roles to the admin
admins.rights << read
admins.rights << create
admins.rights << update
admins.rights << delete
```

rake db:migrate works fine and all table columns are as I expect them to. Just when I run rake db:seed it aborts with the above error. I understand what the error is saying - I just can't see where I am not defining the has_many to roles.

I have gone through the models very closely but can't seem to find what I have missed.

and my model files looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password

    has_many :assignments
    has_many :roles, :through => :assignments

    attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation

    validates_presence_of :email, :on => :create
    validates :password, :confirmation => true
    validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true
    validates_uniqueness_of :email

    #will be using this later to check if the user has access to resources/actions
    # def can?(action, resource)
    #   roles.includes(:rights).for(action, resource).any?
    # end
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :grants
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :users, :through => :assignments
    has_many :rights, :through => :grants  
    scope :for, lambda{|action, resource| 
            where("rights.operation = ? AND rights.resource = ?", 
                  Right::OPERATION_MAPPINGS[action], resource
                 )
          }  
end

class Right < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :operation, :resource
    has_many :grants
    has_many :roles, :through => :grants
    OPERATION_MAPPINGS = {
        "new" => "CREATE",
        "create" => "CREATE",
        "edit" => "UPDATE",
        "update" => "UPDATE",
        "destroy" => "DELETE",
        "show" => "READ",
        "index" => "READ"
    }
end

class Grant < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :right_id, :role_id
    belongs_to :role
    belongs_to :right
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :role
    attr_accessible :role_id, :user_id
end
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ditch the `[]`'s and `{}`'s in the first line, eg:

```
 user = User.create!(email: 'admin@admin.com', first_name: 'Admin', last_name: 'Test', password: 'admin', password_confirmation: 'admin')
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not create one user as array of users. Try delete the square brackets in User.create!()

```
user = User.create!({email: 'admin@admin.com', first_name: 'Admin', last_name: 'Test', password: 'admin', password_confirmation: 'admin'})
```